# Trying to iterate through a returned list of addresses, select one and submit to next php file

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

having a bit of trouble with this one.

This is part of a SOAP WSDL API system.
I send the SOAP API a street address and it looks it up and returns me a WSDL listing of valid addresses. I should be able to click on the correct result and then submit that to my 2nd php file to further process and send to the SOAP API.

I get something back like this (should have multiple addresses back, but it's a testing environment, so only ever get this address. In live platform, I will get multiple addresses back).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <FindServiceProviderLocationIdResponse xmlns="http://www.aapt.com.au/FrontierLink/xsd">
      <serviceProviderLocationList>
        <serviceProviderLocationList>
          <serviceProvider>NBN</serviceProvider>
          <locationList>
            <addressInformation>
              <serviceProvider>NBN</serviceProvider>
              <locationId>LOC000000000002</locationId>
              <address>
                <streetNumber>6</streetNumber>
                <streetName>TEST</streetName>
                <streetType>STREET</streetType>
                <suburb>GLEBE</suburb>
                <state>NSW</state>
                <postcode>2037</postcode>
              </address>
              <displayAddress>6 TEST ST GLEBE NSW 2037</displayAddress>
            </addressInformation>
          </locationList>
        </serviceProviderLocationList>
      </serviceProviderLocationList>
    </FindServiceProviderLocationIdResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

part of my PHP code that should iterate through these results and give me a list of links for the user to click on the correct address (thus submitted to the next php file for processing is).

```
//Display a list of address options to the user
echo '<h1>Please select a location from the list</h1>';

//Squirt out the address list for the user to pick from
foreach($locidRes as $l){
    echo '<a href="qualify.php?locid='.$l['locationId'].'">'.$l['displayAddress'].'</a><br/>';
};

//When the user selects a location ID from the list, we then submit that to the next file -> qualify.php

echo '<hr/>';
echo json_encode($locidRes);
```

I am however getting this error

**Please select a location from the list**

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/getLocationId.php:70 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/getLocationId.php on line 70

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: There are no `locationId` or `displayAddress` elements in that response. Why do you expect them there?

Comment: Also, in php associative arrays and objects are different beasts, so if you need to access those properties they would be `$l->locationId` and `$l->displayAddress`.

Comment: Hi Frederico, sorry, updated with the correct response above. Good point re the property types.

Comment: Ok, have you tried what I suggest in the second comment? Still not working?

Comment: I did actually try that earlier, but got another error. I will try again now and report back.

Comment: Ok, this is what I now get back, Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$locationId in /var/www/html/getLocationId.php on line 70  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$displayAddress in /var/www/html/getLocationId.php on line 70    But it does spit out the SOAP API address result, however it is not clickable.

Comment: Here's the SOAP API result (as I said, not clickable), {"serviceProviderLocationList":{"serviceProviderLocationList":{"serviceProvider":"NBN","locationList":{"addressInformation":{"serviceProvider":"NBN","locationId":"LOC000000000002","address":{"streetNumber":"6","streetName":"TEST","streetType":"STREET","suburb":"GLEBE","state":"NSW","postcode":"2037"},"displayAddress":"6 TEST ST GLEBE NSW 2037"}}}}}

Comment: I have edited the edco output, per your suggestion to look like this now.     echo '<a href="qualify.php?locid='.$l->locationId.'">'.$l->displayAddress.'</a><br/>';

Comment: can you please do a `print_r` of `$l` before the error?

Comment: print_r of $l = stdClass Object ( [serviceProviderLocationList] => stdClass Object ( [serviceProvider] => NBN [locationList] => stdClass Object ( [addressInformation] => stdClass Object ( [serviceProvider] => NBN [locationId] => LOC000000000002 [address] => stdClass Object ( [streetNumber] => 6 [streetName] => TEST [streetType] => STREET [suburb] => GLEBE [state] => NSW [postcode] => 2037 ) [displayAddress] => 6 TEST ST GLEBE NSW 2037 ) ) ) )

Comment: You're missing a couple of levels then. Looks like you need to cycle through `$l->serviceProviderLocationList->locationList`

Comment: I only really need to display to the user the displayAddress and have that clickable. The locationId is what I pass into the 2nd PHP file to process further. PHP isn't my native tongue, but already you have given me some good ideas. Thankyou Federico.